# Speaking android application

Tags: android, text-to-speech, voice-recording

I have a set of some messages which should be speaked by android app. I could use something like [Svox](https://svoxmobilevoices.wordpress.com/), but I don't need to read user input.

I was thinking about using prerecorded words and putting them together myself - could you please show me some way how to do it properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android has a built in feature for [Text To Speech](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html) since API level 4.

Go through this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-text-to-speech-tutorial/) for a step by step guide.

Answer (score 2):

clone this git [project](https://github.com/Kaljurand/Arvutaja)

Its a well architected example for recognizing spoken commands in ( english/estonian )

If you like the approach, there is a [lib project](https://github.com/Kaljurand/K6nele) to use as a service

If you can take the time to follow opensource, this approach to implementing recognized commands is quite good.

Comment: I think the OP asks about text-to-speech, but the projects that you link to are more about speech-to-text, although the first project (Arvutaja) contains text-to-speech as well.